# how to list all downloaded datset from nltk

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, nltk, corpus

I downloaded some of the datasets from nltk using

```
import nltk
import nltk.corpus 
nltk.download()
```

Now I want to list all the downloaded dataset
I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a path where the downloads are stored. It should be `nltk.data.path`.

Also, try using [nltk.data.find](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.data.find):

```py
import os
import nltk

print(os.listdir(nltk.data.find("corpora")))
```